# Regex greedyness REasking

Tags: regex, perl, greedy

I have this text `$line = "config.txt.1"`, and I want to match it with regex and extract the number
part of it. I am using two versions:

```
$line = "config.txt.1";

(my $result) = $line =~ /(\d*).*/;    #ver 1, matched, but returns nothing

(my $result) = $line =~ /(\d).*/;     #ver 2, matched, returns 1

(my $result) = $line =~ /(\d+).*/;    #ver 3, matched, returns 1
```

I think the `*` was sort of messing things around, I have been looking at [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), but still
don't the greedy mechanism in the regex engine. If I start from left of the regex, and potentially there might be no digits in the text, so for ver 1, it will match too. But for
ver 3, it won't match. Can someone give me an explanation for why it is that and how 
I should write for what I want? (potentially with a number, not necessarily single digit)

**Edit**

Requirement: potentially with a number, not necessarily single digit, and match can not capture anything, but should not fail

The output must be as follows (for the above example):

`config.txt`    `1`

Answer (score 2):

The regex `/(\d*).*/` always matches immediately, because it can match zero characters. It translates to *match as many digits at this position as possible (zero or more). Then, match as many non-newline characters as possible*. Well, the match starts looking at the `c` of `config`. Ok, it matches zero digits.

You probably want to use a regex like `/\.(\d+)$/` -- this matches an integer number between a period `.` and the end of string.

Comment: I guess your solution works for lines that has numbers, what it does not? Requirement: `potentially with a number`

Comment: If it does not match, nothing is captured.

Comment: But I don't want to fail the match, as I might want to capture something else in the string

Answer (score 2):

Use the literal '.' as a reference to match before the number:

```
   #!/usr/bin/perl 
    use strict;
    use warnings;

my @line = qw(config.txt file.txt config.txt.1 config.foo.2 config.txt.23 differentname.fsdfsdsdfasd.2444);

my (@capture1, @capture2);
foreach (@line){    
my (@filematch) = ($_ =~ /(\w+\.\w+)/); 
my (@numbermatch) = ($_ =~ /\w+\.\w+\.?(\d*)/);
my $numbermatch = $numbermatch[0] // $numbermatch[1];
    push @capture1, @filematch;
    push @capture2, @numbermatch;
}

print "$capture1[$_]\t$capture2[$_]\n" for 0 .. $#capture1;
```

Output:

```
config.txt  
file.txt    
config.txt  1
config.foo  2
config.txt  23
differentname.fsdfsdsdfasd  2444
```

Comment: And now it will not get the numbers from `config.txt.12`

Comment: This works, can you elaborate on why `/\.txt\.?(\d*)/` and `/\.?(\d*)/` does not work

Comment: `\.?(\d*)` Matches for "A literal `.` or no `.` and 0 - inf digits" Which would basically match everything if followed by `/g` - global match. It would work if you use `\.?(\d+)` - which would require 1 or more digits. I put in the \.? incase you have a format like `config.txt` without a trailing dot, and wanted to capture the 'space'

Comment: What if they are not preceded by `.txt` but any combination of alphabets?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36474/discussion-between-juto-and-flyingfrog)

Comment: Appreciate your work, but that's not what want (have been trying to get it in one line), will upvote though

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `.*` at all. These two statements assign the exact same number:

```
my ($match1) = $str =~ /(\d+).*/;
my ($match1) = $str =~ /(\d+)/;
```

A regex by default matches partially, you do not need to add wildcards.

The reason your first match does not capture a number is because `*` can match zero times as well. And since it does not have to match your number, it does not. Which is why `.*` is actually detrimental in that regex. Unless something is truly optional, you should use `+` instead.

Comment: You mentioned `since it does not have to match your number, it does not`, when does it match, and when it decides to not?

Comment: The `.*` makes it start the match at the start of the string, matching `\d*` to the empty string.

Comment: Interesting, so the regex engine matches from backwards?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I think I figured out myself what I want:

```
my ($match) = $line =~ /\.(\d+)?/;    #this will match and capture any digit 
                                      #number if there was one, and not fail
                                      #if there wasn't one
```

Comment: This will fail to match if `$line` ends with any character other than a dot or a digit.

Answer (score 1):

To capture all digits following a final `.` and not fail the match if the string doesn't end with digits, use `/(?:\.(\d+))?$/`

```
perl -E 'if ("abc.123" =~ /(?:\.(\d+))?$/) { say "matched $1" } else { say "match failed" }'
matched 123
perl -E 'if ("abc" =~ /(?:\.(\d+))?$/) { say "matched $1" } else { say "match failed" }'
matched
```

Comment: Can you please explain the regex a bit? What does `?:` mean?

Comment: @Juto `(?: )` are non-capturing parentheses. The `?:` causes them to function _only_ for grouping without creating another capture to confuse things. That way, I was able to use `(?: )?` to make the whole thing - both the `.` and the digits - into an optional match.

Comment: If you are `not-capturing` the `.` and the numbers, how can you then try to capture the numbers again in the non-capturing group? I exactly want to do that!

Comment: @Juto The outer set of parentheses are non-capturing (`(?: )`), but the inner set are just plain, capturing parentheses (`( )`), so they grab the digits.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think it is very close to what I want, but for capturing, the `?` seems to be not capturing when it could not capture, i.e., `abc.123` after regex would be `matched, but no number`